# memory increase use UIImagePickerController to take photo and save to user's album

Tags: ios, memory, ios8, camera

I'm using `MWPhotoBrowser` to display my photos taken by `UIImagePickerController`.
Here is my code for saving to user's album.

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerdidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

  //  NSDictionary* metadata=info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
//    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]performChanges:^{
//        NSURL* url=info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
//        PHAssetChangeRequest* assetChangeReques=    [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:url];
//        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest* request=[PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.assetCollection];
//        [request addAssets:@[[assetChangeReques placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];
//    }completionHandler:^(BOOL success,NSError* error){
//        if (success) {
//          //  self.previewImgView.image=image;
//        }
//    }];

   ALAssetsLibrary* alassetsLibary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
   [alassetsLibary saveImageData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 1.0f) toAlbum:self.assetCollection.localizedTitle metadata:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] completion:^(NSURL* assetUrl,NSError* error)
 {

   }failure:^(NSError* error){

   }];
   self.previewImgView.image=[info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] getThumbnailWithSize:self.previewImgView.bounds] ;
   alassetsLibary=nil;
   info=nil;

}
```

I have used to ways to save the photo above. But it can't handle the problem same as yours.
In the second method. I have tried to change the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` parameter from 0.1 to 1.0. But it did't work.
I have try to let `alassetsLibary=nil;  info=nil;` But when I open the photoBrowser. The memory increase so fast.

If anybody has solution,please tell me!!
And I wondering how Apple handle with this issue in native camera app as well.
Gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this to save pics to the album:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:((UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]).CGImage
                                 metadata:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]
                          completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"assetURL %@", assetURL);
                                imageURL=[assetURL absoluteString];
                        //save URL for future use      
                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageURL forKey:@"imageurl"];

                          }];


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

Comment: Thanks, my app goes with memory increase when I use the `MWPhotoBrowser` and I have found that the file size of the photo taken by `UIImagePickerController` is among 8-10M. And by the native camera app,the size is 1-3M. Im sure that this is my problem.

Comment: When I change the compress parameter to `0.7f`, the file size become normal. But the problem still!!!